# OSM in QuickMapServices not displaying baselayer image on QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickmapservices

[[image][image: ][1]]I am attempting to load a QuickMapServices OSM baselayer image on QGIS 3.4 LTR and nothing is displayed, even though it says that the layer has been added. Nothing seems wrong with my plug-ins and I cannot seem to figure out why.

Comment: Can you please give more information (screenshots, logs etc.)

Comment: Your CRS needs to be **WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator**

Comment: I have set my CRS to WDS 84/Pseudo Mercator and it still is not displaying the layer.

Comment: Start a new QGIS Project, Load OSM first, then add your polygon layer.